# "All routers are down or won't exit" from a few days

Tags: orbot, android, routers

Few days ago I decided to try Tor at my phone to see if it consumes so much battery. From the beginning it was really good, but two days ago, this started to happen:

[image]

I tried to put a proxy with `localhost:8118` at every app I have installed, but can't get what app is causing me that.

I own a Nexus 4 with Chroma Lollipop with few Google apps and some like Twitter and so (If you want to see a full list I could get it).

Orbot has no relay, exit or entrance node, it has the default config.

Comment: Do you have an application that uses localhost:8118 as a http proxy? Like a browser or a torrent client?

Comment: @UmutSeven I got a browser called ChaosChrome, but as far as OSMonitor showed it does not use the 8118 port...

Comment: My good advice to you for a custom exit node case : use *your own exit nodes* =) Make an exit node at home, or - if yo have a multiple ISP's - multiple nodes. A node at your friend's place could be of use - but don't use "just one"...

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

I set up a custom exit node (which is noiseexit01d at [atlas.torproject.org](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/C6F6B70AD9115C65B618B0AF3FD10B0432626CA9)). I enabled "Transparent Proxy" (so you must asume I'm root). That's when I think the problem came from.

So I deleted that set up and restart the phone, with a random circuit, and I didn't have the problem anymore.

I'm not sure, however, that's the real problem, but It was removed from now.